# D implicitly cast Vector(T) types

Tags: benchmarking, d, dmd, microbenchmark

Compare code fragments A:

```d
struct Vector2(T) {
    // ...

    auto opCast(U)() {
        return U(x, y);
    }

    void opOpAssign(string op)(Vector2 vector) {
        mixin ("x" ~ op ~ "= vector.x;");
        mixin ("y" ~ op ~ "= vector.y;");
    }
}

void main() {
    auto fVec = Vector2!float(1.5, 1.5);
    auto dVec = Vector2!double(1.5, 1.5);

    // Benchmark: Loop following 10 million times.
    fVec += cast(Vector2!float)  dVec;
    dVec -= cast(Vector2!double) fVec;
}
```

with B:

```d
struct Vector2(T) {
    // ...

    void opOpAssign(string op, U)(Vector2!U vector) {
        mixin ("x" ~ op ~ "= vector.x;");
        mixin ("y" ~ op ~ "= vector.y;");
    }
}

void main() {
    auto fVec = Vector2!float(1.5, 1.5);
    auto dVec = Vector2!double(1.5, 1.5);

    // Benchmark: Same as A.
    fVec += dVec;
    dVec -= fVec;
}
```

In my benchmarks (DMD, Win7), A is ~50ms faster than B. Any reason why this is? If A is faster I would like to use it, but I can't get Vector2!double to implicitly cast to a Vector2!float no matter what I try. Any idea on how I can implicitly cast these types? Or is there some argument to why I shouldn't implicitly cast them?

I'm setting up GDC and LDC to do this benchmark with those compilers, but does anyone know offhand if this is a DMD only optimization issue?

Answer (score 3):

Two different instantiations of the same template have nothing more in common than two completely separate types as far as the compiler is concerned. You could declare

```
struct VectorFloat
{
    ...
}

struct VectorDouble
{
    ...
}
```

instead of templatizing `Vector2`, and it would make no difference. `Vector2!float` and `Vector!double` are completely different types. And with any types that you declare, if you want ways to convert between them, you're going to have to declare them - be they `opCast`, `alias this`, constructors, or whatever. I believe that the only way that you're ever going to get *implicit* conversion to work is with `alias this`, though as [ratchet freak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796390/160887) points out, implicitly converting between floats and doubles is *not* how D normally works and is arguably a bad idea.

As to why A is faster than B, I don't know. I would have actually expected it to be the other way around. But depending on what exactly the compiler is doing, it could change later, and it could easily vary from compiler to compiler. And since you're only seeing a 50ms difference over *10 million* iterations, I'd go with the version that makes more sense from an API perspective (whichever you think that is). I'd argue going with the first one though, simply because I don't think that it's a good idea to implicitly convert between float and double, but that's up to you, since it's your code.

By the way, you can use std.conv.to instead of calling `opCast` directly if you want. It's less error-prone that way, since then it'll yell if you screw up defining `opCast`, whereas the compiler is more likely to just do it anyway, since cast is very much a blunt instrument.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't implicitly cast `double` to *single* precision `float`ing point, just like you can't implicitly convert from `long` to `int` because you'll lose precision.

Most languages require you to make it clear when you want to lose precision when converting. and it is best if you follow the existing conventions in the language instead of enforcing your own.

Comment: Sure, but I can't implicitly cast from Vector2!float to Vector2!double either.

Comment: then add a `opAssign(F)(Vector2!F l)if(isImplicitlyConvertible(F,T)){x=l.x;y=l.y;}`